# CF7 file upload image

Tags: jquery, image, upload, contact-form-7

I'm using CF7 to capture user input and for them to upload an image file. I want to display the image file on the screen once its uploaded and before the submit button is pressed.

I can see on the screen the file name, and if I jQuery the input value it says `c:\fakepath\[filename]`.

My jQuery is:

```
var x = jQuery('span.imageid1 input').val();
```

which produces `c:\fakepath\[filename]`

Is it possible to find the local path, as the image is not saved to the WPDB until the user hits submit.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the filename is restricted, this is a security feature. You won't be able to get the full path. See [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath) or [Getting value from <file> gives C:\fakepath\filename, even in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466383/getting-value-from-file-gives-c-fakepath-filename-even-in-linux)

You can however read the selected file and display a thumbnail of the selected image without accessing the filename:

```
function handleFiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    if (!file.type.startsWith('image/')){ continue }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.file = file;
    preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is the div output where the content will be displayed.

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)

This is using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)